# Microsoft access with PHP and PDO

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo

I am trying to connect to my access database but cannot. I have on my Microsoft server 2008 with IIS 7. I keep getting this error message. SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified. Not Sure what I am doing wrong. Any ideas would help.

```
<?php
try {

 $conn = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\\staffing.mdb;Uid=Admin");

}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the connection object like the following and save characters case.

```
$dbName = "E:\\path\\to\\db.mdb";
 $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};charset=UTF-8; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
```

Comment: Thank you that worked Now I just have to figure how to query the access DB with PHP and PDO

Comment: I was able to query the db just can't get my javascript code to work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068866/texboxfield-will-not-auotpopulate-errors-out

Comment: FWIW I had this problem and was tearing my hair out for ages. I was using the driver `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)` instead of the one used in the answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: A year later, and I can say that the real reason I couldn't get this to work is that I hadn't got the [64-bit version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=54920) of the Access driver on my server.