# PDO is not sending output of MS Access DB to php

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo

I am new to PDO but I want this MS Access file to be read with php.

[image]
Since I am new to PDO I have used [this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-an-access-database-with-php)

For some reason the content of the DB is not shown.

```
<?php
$dbName = "PART.MDB";
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    echo $dbName;
    die(" Could not find database file.");
}
else
{
    $i = 0;

    echo $dbName;
    echo(" Was found.");    
    echo '<br /><br />';

    $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");

    $sql = "SELECT Name FROM Part";

    $result = $db->query($sql);
    while ($row = $result->fetch())
    {
        $i++;
        echo 'row '.$i.' '.$row["Name"];
        echo '<br /><br />';
    }
}
?>
```

The output is:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `$dbName = "PART";`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but that did not solve my problem.

Comment: Can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066516/microsoft-access-with-php-and-pdo

Comment: Always when developing and testing code, enable error display. At the top of your script, `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  By default, PDO errors silently. You should also configure your `$db` pdo object to throw exceptions after connecting. `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`